# Contour plot issues python

Tags: python, contour

I've got some data I'm trying to represent via contour plot.

I'm manually filling in the data matrix like so:

```
DPP=[]
cols = [0 for i in range(len(p_values))]
DPP = [cols[:] for i in range(len(eta_values))]

for i in range(len(p_values)):
    for j in range(len(eta_values)):
        DPP[j][i]=dpp[i * len(p_values) + j]
```

And then I try to plot it using contourf:

```
cm=plt.get_cmap('RdBu')
plt.figure()
cs=plt.contourf(p_values,eta_values,DPP)
cs.cmap=cm
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

However something is going wrong, and I'm getting weird data in weird spots, but I really can't figure out what is going wrong, I believe I'm filling the matrix properly. I'm attaching two pictures, one is a simple plot of the data where each line represents a single value in the p_values list:

[image: plot of the data]

And one is the output of the code I've shown above:

[image: the output of the code]

Comment: Found the error, it is in the loop statement that fills the DPP matrix, needed to do i*len(eta_values) + j instead of what is shown